# ffmpeg on windows , how to compile examples?

Tags: ffmpeg, windows-10

I compiled ffmpeg on windows 10 as described in this [guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/WinRT) . I need to compile the doc/examples/extract_mvs.c . whenever I try to run : gcc extract_mvs.c the copiler don't seem to find the included libraries. I also tried to run "make" but the output is that make has nothing to do with extract_mvs.c . I appreciate any help since I am still a newbie :)

Comment: Have you checked the libraries are in the right place?

Comment: Yes I did I followed that guide step by step

Comment: Add path of libraries and your code

Comment: Adding paths solves some problems, but then coming to dependencies between prototype files also invoke the same errors. I think there is another way to compile those examples